# How to go backwards when quoting from something?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, quotes, quotations

I am trying to take a quotation from a book (*The Awakening* if you're interested), but the part I am trying to quote does not well fit my sentence, I am wondering if there is an accepted way to quote one phrase, and then follow it with a bit from earlier on, but in a seamless way. Here is my sentence currently:

> As Edna contemplates what to do after Robert’s letter, she considers that nothing “but Raoul and Etienne...

and I want to include a section saying:

> matters to her.

This is the full section of the book I am quoting from:

> "It makes no difference to me, it doesn't matter about Lèonce Pontellier —
>   but Raoul and Etienne!"

I would ideally end up with something like this:

> As Edna contemplates what to do after Robert’s letter, she considers that nothing “but Raoul and Etienne ... makes [a] difference to [her]" ...

Comment: You could enclose each phrase in separate quotation marks. However, "It makes no difference to me" is such a standard phrase that I wonder whether it's even worth treating it as a quotation, since you have to alter the pronouns anyway.

Comment: @KateBunting Not only that, but the passage you quote first, "but Raoul and Etienne", is merely two common conjunctions and two names, and that is so mundane that I wonder whether it's even worth treating *that* as a quotation either. I would be inclined to paraphrase and not use any quotation-marks.

Comment: See also: [writing.se] Good Luck.